# Unable to start main activity, unable to instantiate

Tags: java, android

I forgot what I've done but the codes work as usual previously. I tried to solve it by searching methods on stackoverflow but most of them does not work for me. I've tried checking all relevant libraries the "Order and Export" but not working and I already include the java class in my manifest. It does not work by cleaning it again and again.

```
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126): Process: com.fyp.atms, PID: 3126
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.fyp.atms/com.fyp.atms.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fyp.atms.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fyp.atms-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.fyp.atms-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fyp.atms.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fyp.atms-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.fyp.atms-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
11-14 01:54:59.685: E/AndroidRuntime(3126):     ... 11 more
11-14 01:54:59.715: I/Process(3126): Sending signal. PID: 3126 SIG: 9
```

Comment: delete all content of bin folder and reconfigure your project build path.

Comment: Hi piyush, sorry i'm new, could explain in details about reconfiguring build path?

Comment: I deleted everything in bin folder and clean to generate it, still not working

Comment: what all libraries you have in your projects.

Comment: post your manifest file..

Comment: Check that line - `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fyp.atms.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fyp.atms-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.fyp.atms-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

Comment: Thanks pals, I have no idea how i solve it... I restarted my eclipse then it works now. lol